# How to to boot Linux from external USB SSD drive, attached to Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb, ssd

Is there way to boot Linux from `external USB SSD drive`, attached to Windows 7 machine?(without altering or modification the Windows Boot Configuration Data(BCD)) The same way as boot with bootable **Linux Live CD**, by selecting USB boot device in the Boot Device Menu (F12) before windows startup.
I installed Linux on USB external SSD drive, but it not booting when I select "Removable Devices" in Windows boot menu before windows start up. Didn't find what can be the problem. Possibly Windows have poor support for booting from USB devices.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe should work.  If you go to the boot device menu and the external drive is displayed as an option, you should be able to boot from it if that drive is bootable.  It sounds like the problem is with the configuration of external drive.  One thing to check: plug the external drive directly into a USB port on the computer itself, not a USB hub.

Another thing to check: try using the external drive to boot another computer just as a test.  I've run into situations where I installed Linux on an external SSD using an old XP-age computer and the drive would boot on that computer but not another computer with more current hardware.  I reinstalled Linux on the external drive using the newer computer and it then worked on all machines.

Comment: Edit: I used wrong item in boot menu. When I set boot order to `"USB storage"`, it show black screen with message "GRUB Loading. Welcome to GRUB!" and a blinking cursor. Can't wait forever to verify if it hung or stalled.

Comment: Booting should start within a few seconds of seeing the GRUB message.  I would just try reinstalling it.

Comment: Linux installation process asked me to install the boot loader to Master boot record at `"/dev/sda"`(my internal hard drive), and to get sort of dual-boot system, but I specified to install bootloader to `"/dev/sdb"` (SSD drive), because I don't want modification of Windows Boot Configuration Data (BCD) on an internal hard drive, where is installed Windows OS.

Comment: For what you want to do, /dev/sdb would be the right location and it sounds like grub is working.  When you installed Linux on the external drive, did you format it as a bootable drive (you designate the partition as a boot partition, which provides a MBR)?

Comment: I have a separate /boot partition (ext4) and specified **bootable flag: on.**

Comment: It sounds like you're doing everything right.  I have heard of problems with multiple partitions not all being recognized on SDD drives.  If you can see all of the partitions in Linux (say with a LiveDVD boot), you might try making sdb1 the boot partition if that is not the one you are using.  Another thought, is the computer BIOS UEFI (Windows 8.x)?  That can sometimes require special handling.  You might want to pose the problem on a forum specific to the Linux distro to have the best chance of getting input from someone familiar with the problem.

Comment: The partitions are: `/dev/sdb1 /boot  ext4 boot flag`, `/dev/sdb2 "/" root ext4`, `/dev/sdb3 linux-swap`. When view SSD drive from GParted liveCD, both ext4 partitions have status "Not mounted" and swap partition is"Not active", is that correct? As I have read, GRUB might have poor support for ext4 filesystem? Also, possibly it can be Linux bug related to some kind of BIOS. The BIOS is AHCI.

Comment: From what little I know, AHCI can be tricky.  You might want to research potential problems and solutions.  Other than that, I'm drawing a blank.  You need some input from someone with more specific knowledge than I have.

Comment: One note: the bootloader should be installed specifically into the **drive** `"/dev/sdb"`, not to the partiton (like "/dev/sdb1" or "/dev/sdb2"): that's correct?

Comment: GRUB contains several components.  One is stored in the MBR (which would be in the boot partition, like sdb1).  The other is in the filesystem.  There can also be a third component for which there are a number of optional locations.  Generally, you don't need to deal with that level of detail.  If you specify the drive (sdb), the installer will figure out where to put GRUB's pieces.